# Photon PRC Master Client

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, photon

I have a gameObject called GameController with PhotonView script attached to it.
I have 2 players - editor and standalone, so in my scene (once connected to the room) I have 2 game objects: "Editor GameController" and "Standalone GameController". Editor is the master client.

I have 2 RPC methods: `PostedBlinds` and `CompletedMatchingCards`. Both with input parameter of string and `Debug.Log`s inside.
Standalone calls for method `PostedBlinds`, targeting the master.

```
_photonView.RPC("PostedBlindes", RpcTarget.MasterClient, "test");
```

The RPC Method code:

```
[PunRPC]
public void PostedBlindes(string dataObjectJson, PhotonMessageInfo messageInfo)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("PostedBlindes: {0}. Sender: {1}", gameObject.name, messageInfo.Sender.NickName);
}
```

**Log: PostedBlindes: Editor GameController: Sender: Standalone.**  (As expected)

After that, Standalone calls method `CompletedMatchingCards`, targeting the master.

```
_photonView.RPC("CompletedMatchingCards", RpcTarget.MasterClient, "test2");
```

The RPC Method code:

```
    [PunRPC]
public void CompletedMatchingCards(string dataObjectJson, PhotonMessageInfo messageInfo)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("CompletedMatchingCards: {0}. Sender: {1}", gameObject.name, messageInfo.Sender.NickName);
}
```

**Log: CompletedMatchingCards: Standalone GameController: Sender: Standalone**

Method CompletedMatchingCards doesn't get called on the master client (Editor) even though it targets the master client.

I've tried rebuilding with different App Version. Didn't work.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: It's easier if you share the code.

Comment: @JohnTube, done.

Comment: So both RPC methods have the same signature and target and belong to the same PhotonView, one works and one doesn't, is that it? Take a look at the RPCs list under PhotonServerSettings to debug it, Refresh it or log hash code from both clients (see [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent#shortcuts_for_rpc_names)). You can increase the log level in PhotonServerSettings. You can listen for incoming events using OnEvent callback, RPC event code is 200.

Comment: The second method, "CompletedMatchingCards", works. But the method is executed on the client that fires it, not on the master client.
BTW, I don't think I can log in runtime the hash code.
When I switch platforms, I need to refresh the RPC list or does it stays the same?

Comment: Maybe the Editor is disconnected? maybe a client switch happened between the two calls and the Standalone became the new MasterClient? can you log the list of actors and their ActorNumber and whether their local or MasterClient in each RPC method?
What happens if you call "PostedBlindes" again?